# Osmdroid render not expected like that - TileSource PublicTransport

Tags: android, osmdroid

i've got some trouble with an app wich need to use the OSMPublicTransport tilesource.

Click [here](http://www.casimages.com/i/150423021825954740.png.html) to see the **strange** MapView. So, **why** is this ugly thing in my app ?
Other tilesource work like a charm.

I don't know why it shows me the mapview like this. 
I was waiting for a result like the official [website](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/48.5650/7.7117&layers=T)

Here is my *XML file* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tilesource="OSMPublicTransport" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here how I declare *my view* :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            mapView = FindViewById<MapView> (Resource.Id.mapview);

            mapView.SetTileSource (TileSourceFactory.PublicTransport);

            mapView.SetBuiltInZoomControls (true);
            mapView.SetMultiTouchControls (true);
       }
```

In advance, thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OSMPublicTransport tiles are overlay tiles. They are meant to be displayed on top of existing imagery. So use a regular tile source, and then add a new TilesOverlay for the overlay imagery:

```
// Add tiles layer
MapTileProviderBasic provider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
provider.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT);
TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(provider, this.getBaseContext());
mapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
```

Answer (score 0):

The tiles url for osmdroid PublicTransport is: http://openptmap.org/tiles/

The tiles url you mention (official osm public transport map) has the following structure: http://b.tile.thunderforest.com/transport/

You can probably raise an issue in osmdroid, as their url seems obsolete.

You can also build your own tile source. Quite easy, by looking at [osmdroid TileSourceFactory](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/tileprovider/tilesource/TileSourceFactory.java) source to get examples.